# Convert Callback to Promise in Publish Subscribe Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, callback

Let say we have a service called `A` and it has the function `subscribe(callback)`. The subscription from the service is an open connection that can receive data at any time, and the data can be accessed through the callback.
Can we convert this callback to promise? if so, how?

Sample

```
A.subscribe((error, data) => {
    // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we convert this callback to promise?

Not just *one* promise, no, because a promise can only be settled *once*, with a single fulfillment value (on success), but you have a *series* of values (often called an "observable"). So you can't convert that to return a promise, unless of course you want the promise to only fulfill with just *one* of the values (the first, for instance).

You could convert it to an asynchronous iterator (perhaps using an `async` generator function). As the name implies, an asynchronous iterator provides a series of values asynchronously, by returning a *series* of promises. I can't say whether an asynchronous iterator is applicable to your use case, but it's the closest thing to a promise-based observable that comes to mind.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/zenparsing/4e65592f184dafc82125) an observable-to-async-iterator implementation designed for Angular's observables, but which could be adapted as necessary. (Sadly, there's no license indicated, so I can't copy it into the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

**duplexStream**

As TJ suggests, you cannot represent a subscription with a *single* promise. However, you only need one variable and the ability to recreate the promise. I have used a technique similar to the one described in TJ's link but with notable differences in abstraction. `duplexStream` below gives the caller a `read` function for any stream consumers in your program, and a `write` function to use for stream producers -

```js
function duplexStream () {
  let t = defer()
  async function* read () {
    while (true) yield await t.deferred
  }
  function write (err, value) {
    if (err) t.reject(err)
    else t.resolve(value)
    t = defer()
  }
  return [read, write]
}
```

`defer` is a simple abstraction to provide an externally controlled promise -

```js
function defer () {
  let resolve, reject
  return { deferred: new Promise((res, rej) => (resolve = res, reject = rej)), resolve, reject }
}
```

Let's say we have two HTML elements -

```html
<p id="foo"></p>
<p id="bar"></p>
```

**channel**

`duplexStream` is generic and not tethered to a particular library or class. We can now use it to convert an observable to an async iterator. Note `read` can be called multiple times and all readers will get values passed to `write`. `write` can also be given to any number of producers.  By providing `read` and `write` as generic functions to the caller, these handlers can be managed during ordinary `publish` and `subscribe` events.

Abstracting on top of `duplexStream`, we create a `channel` with familiar `publish` and `subscribe` methods -

```js
function channel ([read, write] = duplexStream()) {
  return {
    publish(v) {
      if (v instanceof Error)
        write(v)
      else
        write(null, v)
    },
    async subscribe(onValue, onError = console.error) {
      while (true)
        try {
          for await (const v of read())
            onValue(v)
        }
        catch (err) {
          onError(err)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Given some `<form>` -

```html
<form id="myform">
  <button type="button" name="b1">▶️ next value</button>
  <button type="button" name="b2">⏺ some error</button>
  <pre><output name="foo"></output></pre>
  <pre><output name="bar"></output></pre>
</form>
```

We create a channel, `A`, and make two `<button>` publishers and two `<output>` subscribers -

```js
const f = document.forms.myform
const A = channel()

// publishers
f.b1.addEventListener("click", event => A.publish(String(new Date)))
f.b2.addEventListener("click", event => A.publish(Error("error")))

// subscribers
A.subscribe(v => f.foo.value += v + "\n")
A.subscribe(v => f.bar.value += v + "\n")
```

Each click of ▶️ will `publish` a value to each `subscribe`r -

| render preview |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview] |

Clicking ⏺ will `publish` an error to the console, yet subsequent publishes using ▶️ will still work.

**demo**

Run the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function duplexStream () {
  let t = defer()
  async function* read () { while (true) yield await t.deferred }
  function write (err, value) { if (err) t.reject(err); else t.resolve(value); t = defer() }
  return [read, write]
}

function defer () {
  let resolve, reject
  return { deferred: new Promise((res, rej) => (resolve = res, reject = rej)), resolve, reject }
}

function channel ([read, write] = duplexStream()) {
  return {
    publish(v) { if (v instanceof Error) write(v); else write(null, v) },
    async subscribe(onValue, onError = console.error) {
      while (true) try { for await (const v of read()) onValue(v) } catch (err) { onError(err) }
    }
  }
}

const f = document.forms.myform
const A = channel()
f.b1.addEventListener("click", event => A.publish(String(new Date)))
f.b2.addEventListener("click", event => A.publish(Error("error")))
A.subscribe(v => f.foo.value += v + "\n")
A.subscribe(v => f.bar.value += v + "\n")
```

```css
pre { margin: 0.5rem 0; }
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <button type="button" name="b1">▶️ next value</button>
  <button type="button" name="b2">⏺ some error</button>
  <pre><output name="foo"></output></pre>
  <pre><output name="bar"></output></pre>
</form>
```